# Is there a way of not generating the same number with the method I'm using?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have to print a bingo board by using a 2D array and the method I'm using makes logical sense but I can't seem ti figure out why it's still generating same numbers. Any thoughts? I've tried the arraylist but it's a 1D array, if theres a probability it can be a 2D can someone please help. 
*****Updated, so i used a bit of everything and I'm still jammed.

```
package bingo.arrays.assignment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class bingoooooooooooooo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] card = new int[5][5];
        display1(card);

    }

    public static void display1(int[][] card) {
        int[] colm = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

        int v = 1, z = 15;
        int x = 10000;
       List l = new ArrayList();
        for (int i : colm) {
           l.add(i);
       }
        Collections.shuffle(l);
        //do {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                boolean numberFound = false;
                while (!numberFound) {
                    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * z) + v;

                    if (!checkNumber(number1, card, j)) {
                        break;
                    }

                    card[i][j] = number1;
                    System.out.print("|" + card[i][j]);
                }

//                if (card[i][j] > 25) {
//                x++;
//                }
            }

            v = v + 15;
            z = z + 15;
            System.out.println(" ");

        }
        //}while (true);
    }

public static boolean checkNumber(int number, int[][] card, int j) {

    for(int a = 0; a <= j; a++) {

    if(card[i][a] == number) return false;
  }

  return true;
}






}
```

Comment: Create a `List`, fill it with numbers (sequentially, so you can use a loop), use `Collections.shuffle` to randomize the value.  You might also be able to use a `Set` of some kind and keep adding numbers to it until it reaches the required size...

Comment: Let's talk about sets, baby. Let's talk about you and me. Let's talk about all the good things. And the bad things that may be. Let's talk about sets.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have overlapping ranges, the number can fall within the range of `0` to `z` plus `v`.  What's happening is a number is been generate in the very low range, but `v` isn't large enough to move it beyond the range of the previous set

For example...

`z == 130`, `v == 13`

```
(0.289 * 130) + 31 = 68
(0.304 * 130) + 31 = 70
(0.934 * 130) + 31 = 152
(0.85 * 130) + 31 = 141
(0.902 * 130) + 31 = 148
```

`z == 145`, `v == 13`

```
(0.731 * 145) + 46 = 152
(0.672 * 145) + 46 = 143
(0.016 * 145) + 46 = 48
(0.292 * 145) + 46 = 88
(0.35 * 145) + 46 = 96
```

You can see that numbers in both sets are overlapping with each other. The problem only gets worse as `z` get's larger, as it has more scope to generate overlapping numbers.

Now, I'm sure there's some really awesome mathamtical forumal you could use, but I'm to lazy (and dumb) for that, instead, I'd use a `Set` of some kind to generate a random series of 25 numbers.  This will ensure that each value is unique

```
public static void display1(int[][] card) {

    // Create the set
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(5 * 5);
    // Keep looping until we get 25 numbers
    while (numbers.size() < 5 * 5) {
        // Generate a random number
        numbers.add((int)Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
    }
    // This is just because I'm lazy...
    List<Number> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            // Assign the value to the array...
            card[i][j] = (int)listOfNumbers.remove(0);
        }

    }

    // Add just for printing...you could do this in the previous loop
    // but I just wanted to keep it clean...
    for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("|%3d", card[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("|");

    }
}
```

Which will print something like...

```
|  0|  2| 71|  9| 74|
| 16| 22| 87| 24| 28|
| 93| 30| 33| 40| 41|
| 42| 49| 50| 51| 52|
| 55| 56| 59| 60| 63|
```

Now, if you aren't to attached to the array, you can use something like...

```
int index = (row * 5 + col);
```

to calculate the `index` offset into the `List` for a given row/col

```
for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++) {
        int index = (i * 5 + j);
        System.out.printf("|%3d", listOfNumbers.get(index));
    }
    System.out.println("|");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be you are only checking the previous number.

You need to loop through all of the numbers in the current section like this:

```
boolean numberFound = false;
while(!numberFound) {
  int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * z) + v;

  if(!checkNumber(number1, card, j)) break;

  card [i][j]=number1;
  System.out.print("|" + card[i][j]);
}

public static boolean checkNumber(int number, int[][] card, int j) {
  for(int a = 0; a <= j; a++) {
    if(card[i][a] == number) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: in the checknumber method whats the value of i? should the display method be void or int to prevent this?

Comment: You should add a parameter to pass in i. Take a look a MadProgrammers answer, it's much more thorough.